# `os.path.getsize()` slow on Network Drive (Python, Windows)

Tags: python, windows, performance, networking, profiling

I have a program that iterates over several thousand PNG files on an SMB shared network drive (a 2TB Samsung 970 Evo+) and adds up their individual file sizes. Unfortunately, it is very slow. After profiling the code, it turns out 90% of the execution time is spent on one function:

`filesize += os.path.getsize(png)`

where each `png` variable is the filepath to a single PNG file (of the several thousands) in a for loop that iterates over each one obtained from `glob.glob()` (which, to compare, is responsible for 7.5% of the execution time).

[image]

The code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/SsDCFHLX

Clearly there is something about obtaining the filesize over the network that is extremely slow, but I'm not sure what. Is there any way I can improve the performance? It takes just as long using  `filesize += os.stat(png).st_size` too.

When the PNG files are stored on the computer locally, the speed is not an issue. It specifically becomes a problem when the files are stored on another machine that I access over the local network with a gigabit ethernet cable. Both are running Windows 10.

**[2022-08-21 Update]**

I tried it again with a 10 gigabit network connection this time and noticed something interesting. The very first time I run the code on the network share, the profiler looks like this:

[image]

but if I run it again afterward, `glob()` takes up significantly less time while `getsize()` is about the same:

[image]

if I instead run this code with the PNG files stored on a local NVMe drive (WD SN750) rather than a newtwork drive, here's what the profiler looks like:

[image]

It seems like once it is run for a second time on the network share, something has gotten cached that allows `glob()` to run much faster on the network share, at around the same speed it would run at on the local NVMe drive. But `getsize()` remains extremely slow, about 1/10th of the speed as when local.

Can somebody help me understand these two points:

- Why is `getsize()` so much slower on the network share? Is there something that can be done to speed it up?
- Why is `glob()` slow the first time on the network share but not when I run it again immediately afterward?

Comment: Operations are done synchronously so each operation require a RTT which is a bit expensive. Regarding how the software stack is implemented, many RTT might be needed (due to possibly many synchronous calls done internally). Doing many multithreaded operation simultaneously should help a lot to reduce this overhead but it is still sub-optimal. One solution would be to use async IO operations but I did not found function of the Win32 API for that so far (I know Windows can do it internally since some C# does that, IDK if the Windows' Samba implementation supports it internally though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why `getsize()` is as slow as it is over the network, however to speed it up you could try calling it concurrently:

```py
import os
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def get_total_filesize_concurrently(paths):
    total = 0

    with ThreadPool(10) as pool:
        for size in pool.imap_unordered(lambda path: os.path.getsize(path), paths):
            total += size

    return total


print(get_total_filesize_concurrently([
    "E:\Path\To\File.txt",
    "E:\Path\To\File2.txt"
    "E:\Path\To\File3.txt"
    ...
]))
```

You can also play around with the number of threads defined in `ThreadPool(10)` to potentially increase performance even further.

Comment: This was a good idea, this was a huge performance increase. Usually around 7 times faster if I used 50 threads (on an i7 5960x cpu).

Comment: After benchmarking on 3780 PNG files (10 test runs each for 7 to 200 threads) I determined 24 threads was optimal. Not 100% sure why when my CPU has 16 threads. Here's a chart of the average over the 10 test runs, seconds on the left, threads on the bottom: https://i.imgur.com/qKav0F0.png

Comment: Something else to point out is that I combined your answer with the function `get_filesize_win32()` defined by @sherpya below, but that ended up being about 10% slower than using `os.path.getsize()` as you do here.

Comment: Very interesting results, thanks for sharing. Also are the files in the network drive encrypted by any chance? That might add some kind of overhead as well.

Comment: I expect the number of core not to be very relevant here unless the cores are saturated which should not be the case. The number of thread modulate the number of parallel requests done over the network. The kind of network and the RTT plays a big role in optimal parameters. Storage device and the Samba server should also have a bounded queue size so having more in-flight parallel requests than the queue size should not improve performance.

Comment: @svilen, no, there isn't any encryption. Also, I tested again with different hardware (only a  1 gigabit connection rather than 10) and this is what the graph looks like: https://i.imgur.com/Kmji9wu.png It seems like it requires much more threads when the interface is slower. Also, "fastfilesize" in that graph is the implementation given by sherpya, which actually was faster on a one gigabit connection. Here's the difference on 10 gigabit: https://i.imgur.com/x0co5dZ.png. Interesting the two method cross after a given number of threads on the 10 gigabit connection but not for 1 gigabit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GetFileSizeEx`. You cannot have code with less syscalls.

This is a trimmed down code from this gist: https://gist.github.com/Pagliacii/774ed5d3ea78a36cdb0754be6a25408d

```py
from ctypes import windll, wintypes
from ctypes import Structure, c_longlong, byref, POINTER, WinError

class LARGE_INTEGER(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('QuadPart', c_longlong)]

CreateFileW = windll.kernel32.CreateFileW
CreateFileW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.LPVOID,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.HANDLE)
CreateFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

CloseHandle = windll.kernel32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)
CloseHandle.restype = wintypes.BOOL

GetFileSizeEx = windll.kernel32.GetFileSizeEx
GetFileSizeEx.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, POINTER(LARGE_INTEGER))
GetFileSizeEx.restype = wintypes.BOOL

GENERIC_READ = 31
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
FILE_SHARE_DISABLE = 0
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80


def get_filesize_win32(path):
    size = LARGE_INTEGER()
    handle = CreateFileW(path,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_DISABLE,
        None, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        None)

    try:
        result = GetFileSizeEx(handle, byref(size))
        if not result:
            raise WinError()
        return size.QuadPart
    finally:
        CloseHandle(handle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_filesize_win32(__file__))
```

Comment: This does improve it decently (30% to 45% in my testing), but do you have an intuition behind why the syscalls over the network are so slow in the first place? In my case it was a 10 gigabit connection with an NVMe drive in the target server but it's still significantly slower than when the pngs are local.

Comment: in a shared write networked filesystem the server had to fight with locks, also smb protocol is slow and samba implementation is even slower

Answer (score -2):

You Can Try Getting **Path** From **pathlib**

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

If This Did Not Help, Learn More About This Python Module [[PathLib]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: That just obtains the path, but doesn't speed up the operation of obtaining the file size.